# How to print an interval of values from $rbp in gdb?

Tags: assembly, gdb, 64-bit

If `x /w $rbp + 0x18` prints the address and a value for that address, is there some way I can print an interval of addresses and values from the `$rbp`?

Something like `x /w $rbp +- 0x18`, i.e. the range from `$rbp - 0x18` to `$rbp + 0x18`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from gdb : FMT is a repeat count followed by a format letter and a size letter.:

```
x/48w $rbp-0x18
```

Comment: Some minor errors in there, $rpb should be $rbp and 0x18 should be added for hexadecimal, but I get the point. Thank you ! :)